# Run a script after starting tomcat at k8s pod startup

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes

I'm trying to run a pod-bootstrapping script (which basically runs a java program) after tomcat is started in the pod. My pod runs a single tomcat-based container. Here is the snippet that I'm working and re-working on:

```
     - image: myreg/mydir/myimg:local
       name: tomcat-adminapp
       command: ["/bin/sh"]
       args: ["-c", "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh && /scripts/runUpg.sh"]
```

runUpg.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -l $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib/
chmod 755 $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib/*
java -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib/*" com.myclass.Upg <args> 
tail -f /dev/nul
```

It is starting tomcat but my script execution fails. When I exec into the pod, I see the war is exploded, CATALINA_HOME is set and tomcat process is running. But I see following script errors in kubectl logs:

> ls: cannot access '/userhome/tomcat/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib/': No such file or directory
>   chmod: cannot access '/userhome/tomcat/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib/*': No such file or directory
>   Error: Could not find or load main class com.myclass.Upg
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myclass.Upg

From the error I'm guessing the shell script might not be waiting for tomcat to finish its startup. I'm not sure why..

When I manually run the script from inside the pod, it runs fine.

Any pointers here are appreciated..

**Update:** I confirmed it is indeed the timing issue. When I use `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh && sleep 60 && /scripts/runUpg.sh`, the script seems to run fine. But I think this is hack-ish and not the right way to achieve a call to a class within the webapp.

Answer (score 3):

Consider postStart hook to execute a script after the container is started.

sample reference

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things look "suspicious" to me:

1. `/userhome/tomcate/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib` - shouldn't it be `/user/home`?  (its just a side note, I'll assume you've defined it correctly)
2. Real issue. I don't remember how exactly the tomcat scripts are defined but event without kubernetes you can try to run the tomcat startup script and immediately run something like `ls` on the lib folder. The chances that the folder indeed won't exist and here is why (in my understanding, again):

Tomcat (as a standalone process) was written in a way that it will run "always" but in some points of time you could place "WARs" into webapps folder and it will extract the WAR and start the appliaction. Then you could later, again, place another war and so forth. In other words, **Lifecycle of Tomcat as a process is not bound to the lifecycle of the application**

The startup process of the tomcat itself is supposed to read the configurations, create HTTP connector to listen on port 8080 or something and thats it, after this point the script is done, the tomcat is started.

In terms of solution:

Don't rely on tomcat to create a classpath of your process for you, its just wrong.
Instead you can:

1. Wrap your process into WAR so that the tomcat will manage it as well, again it can server many WARs not just one
2. Create a sidecar container with your application, so that 2 containers will run in the pod side-by-side. This is a kubernetes way of doing things and probably its the best solution. In any case the `com.myclass.Upg` process should be self-contained (meaning contain its own dependencies).

Comment: 1. The class being executed is wrapped in a jar which resides in the war that exists in the container at tomcat startup. Just the call to the main() is from an external script.

2. The purpose of this pod is entirely to just need to run an executable at pod-startup and go away once the executable exits. I can do this in the main container without needing a side-car I think.

Comment: Is it in the same war as the application?

Comment: Yes it is the same war as the application. So I want tomcat to startup my application and after that, I want to run a class from within it.  Also, any commands I string with `&&` after the startup.sh of tomcat seems to execute fine. It is just that the application is taking time to come up.  (Updated my original post)

Comment: Think I could not drop a war but drop an exploded war instead so that all jars are available on the disk even before tomcat make the app working.

Comment: There is another solution then. Web apps are coming with a lifecycle bound to the lifecycle of the WAR. So instead of running another process, you can create a listener that will be called automatically be the tomcat when your war is up. This listener is a java code so that you can merely create a Upg object and run its method. See paragraph 5 about servlet context listeners here (you need to implement contextInitialized method) https://www.journaldev.com/1945/servletcontextlistener-servlet-listener-example#servlet-context-listener

Comment: Thanks @Mark Bramnik. That looks like the solution. Would I be able to send arguments to the class through listener ? I need to read up on it..

Comment: Sure Its a java code. So you can read arguments from some properties file, access web.xml (war descriptor) or use any other location - even get the arguments from the DB if you wish :)